# Why is react-calendar-timeline ignoring child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-calendar-timeline

I have a custom react-calendar-timeline component. It looks something like this:

```
import Timeline, { TimelineHeaders } from 'react-calendar-timeline';

const CustomTimeline = () => {
  return (
      <Timeline 
        // props...
      >
        <TimelineHeaders>
          // My custom timeline headers...
        </TimelineHeaders>
      </Timeline>
  );
};
```

I want to move `TimelineHeaders` into a new component so that I can reduce the amount of code in the `CustomTimeline` component and add some custom styles. This was my attempt using styled-components:

```
import { TimelineHeaders } from 'react-calendar-timeline';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledTimelineHeaders = styled(TimelineHeaders)`
  // custom styles here
`;

const CustomTimelineHeaders = ({ ...props }) => {
  return (
    <StyledTimelineHeaders {...props}>
      // custom headers here
    </StyledTimelineHeaders>
  );
};
```

And of course, the original timeline would now look like this:

```
import Timeline from 'react-calendar-timeline';
import CustomTimelineHeaders from './CustomTimelineHeaders';

const CustomTimeline = () => {
  return (
      <Timeline 
        // props...
      >
        <CustomTimelineHeaders />
      </Timeline>
  );
};
```

My problem is that the `Timeline` does not seem to recognize the `TimelineHeaders` as a child when I use the custom component. Rather than using my custom styles, it goes back to the default headers and completely ignores the custom component. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Why not put everything but TimelineHeaders into the refactored component? Even assuming that isn’t the problem, if the library typically uses a TimelineHeaders component I’d argue it’s better to refactor based on library convention even if it’s incrementally less elegant.

Comment: @DaveNewton That does work but it doesn't answer my question. I would imagine that the jsx returned from `CustomTimelineHeaders` is exactly the same as if I rendered it directly inside the `Timeline`. I'm wondering why these are being treated differently

Comment: You’d have to look to see what goes on in that component, and how it’s used by the parent. There’s no generic answer.